# hint.js:96 Uncaught ReferenceError: isUndefined is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I run my AngularJS app, my index.html file loads OK however my base.html file with AngularJS does not load its content. This is the error I see in the console:

```
hint.js:96 Uncaught ReferenceError: isUndefined is not defined
at toDebugString (hint.js:96)
at hint.js:191
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at hint.js:190
at hint.js:313
at ensure (hint.js:234)
at module (hint.js:311)
at angular.module (hint.js:1184)
at angular.module (hint.js:1334)
at angular.js:2837
```

I am not sure what this hint.js file is and or where isUndefined is.

Here are my javascript sources:

```
<script src="/static/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="/static/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/angularui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the network tab in the Developer Console to see the loading of the  `hint.js` file.

Comment: i found it, but i'm not sure why a chrome extension is the URL? the app does not work in other browsers. 

Request URL: chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate since the error message is different, but the "This question already has an answer here" link did fix it for me (disable AngularJS Batarang extension). I had the exact same error message as jeffca.